# How to get an entire row in an array using awk(each column in separate array element)

Tags: shell, awk

I have a tab delimited file that has 17 columns and about 4000 rows.Some of the columns have `String` values with spaces. I want to take an entire row in an array so that each column value(including space) of that row comes into a separate element of an `array`. I tried to do that by `awk` command.But its not working

```
arr=( $(awk -v var="$var" -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} ( ($2 == var) && ($3!="\.") ){print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17}' c01_trinotate_annotation_report_e_0.001.xls)
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify in what way it's not working?

Comment: The problem is I found some values are missing in the array. Suppose there is a value in a column "abc def ghi".  But I get only "abc" not "abc def ghi" in the array..

Answer (score 0):

```
eval arr=( $(awk -v var="$var" -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} ( ($2 == var) && ($3!="\.") ){for (i=1; i<=17; i++) {printf "\"%s\" ", $i;}}' c01_trinotate_annotation_report_e_0.001.xls))
```

There were two problems.  First, the string containing blanks had to be enclosed in quotes.  Second, the quoting needed to be run through an eval in order to properly process the quoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a file, and treat each row as a bash array, why not do it in bash instead of awk?

```sh
while IFS=$'\t' read -ra row; do
    if [[ ${row[1]} == $var ]] && [[ ${row[2]} != "." ]]; then
        # do something with "${row[@]}"
    fi
done < file
```